# How do I guarantee to the compiler that the type I'm using is a struct with fields X and Y?

Tags: struct, rust, traits

So, I'm attempting to make chess inside of Rust, but I've run into a problem.

I have a `new` function that is the *exact same* across all my pieces (which are structs of their own)... so obviously, when I realized this, I got to work. They already had a shared trait to guarantee that they could all use `movement`, so I just tried implementing the `new` function inside of the Piece trait...

and after almost an hour of intensive Googling, I still haven't got an answer to this puzzle.

Rust simply won't let me create a new object using the `Self` type.

```rust
/// The piece trait. This guarantees that every single piece
/// can move.
pub trait Piece {
    /// The movement function. Returns either an error, or a
    /// vector containing the new position.
    fn movement(&self) -> Result<Vec<usize>, anyhow::Error>;
    fn new(x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Some(Self { x, y }) // Code fails to compile here.
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error[E0423]: expected function, tuple struct or tuple variant, found self type `Self`
  --> src/pieces.rs:19:8
   |
19 |         Some(Self(x, y))
   |              ^^^^ not a function, tuple struct or tuple variant
   |
   = note: can't use `Self` as a constructor, you must use the implemented struct
```

Comment: Code may not match your error code:  `Some(Self { x, y }) // Code fails to compile here.`, but the error message uses parens (not curly brackets): `19 |         Some(Self(x, y))`

Comment: You don't. Traits don't know about fields. Therefore default trait methods can't use fields of `Self`.

Comment: Just an idea: If your all other(pieces) types are constructed by `Self { x, y }` then maybe you should design a single struct  type with common behaviors implemented(new, move, etc...), then you should create traits and implement it for distinguishing features

Comment: A trait is probably the wrong way to implement the different behaviours of chess pieces, since you will never need to extend the set of implementations. Life will be a lot simpler with an enum for the different pieces, and you won't end up needing dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @PeterHall good idea! I will try to make use of that.

Comment: @PeterHall sure enum will still be needed with trait solution, but I am not a fan of writing enum matches where the logic should be, IMHO it should be layered which would be more clean with traits like `PieceType::Horse => Horse::move(&mut piece, pos_x, pos_y)`, where it will be still static dispatch.